# std::map<>::insert using non-copyable objects and uniform initialization

Tags: c++, c++11, noncopyable, movable

Have a look at the following code:

```
#include <utility>
#include <map>

// non-copyable but movable
struct non_copyable {
    non_copyable() = default;

    non_copyable(non_copyable&&) = default;
    non_copyable& operator=(non_copyable&&) = default;

    // you shall not copy
    non_copyable(const non_copyable&) = delete;
    non_copyable& operator=(const non_copyable&) = delete;
};

int main() {
    std::map<int, non_copyable> map;
    //map.insert({ 1, non_copyable() });  < FAILS
    map.insert(std::make_pair(1, non_copyable()));
    // ^ same and works
}
```

Compiling this snippet fails when uncommenting the marked line on g++ 4.7. The error produced indicates that `non_copyable` can't be copied, but I expected it to be moved.

Why does inserting a `std::pair` constructed using uniform initialization fail but not one constructed using `std::make_pair`? Aren't both supposed to produce rvalues which can be successfully moved into the map?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[This is a complete rewrite. My earlier answer had nothing to do with the problem.]

The `map` has two relevant `insert` overloads:

- `insert(const value_type& value)`, and
- `<template typename P> insert(P&& value)`.

When you use the simple list-initializer `map.insert({1, non_copyable()});`, all possible overloads are considered. But only the first one (the one taking `const value_type&`) is found, since the other doesn't make sense (there's no way to magically guess that you meant to create a pair). The first over­load doesn't work of course since your element isn't copyable.

You can make the second overload work by creating the pair explicitly, either with `make_pair`, as you already described, or by naming the value type explicitly:

```
typedef std::map<int, non_copyable> map_type;

map_type m;
m.insert(map_type::value_type({1, non_copyable()}));
```

Now the list-initializer knows to look for `map_type::value_type` constructors, finds the relevant mova­ble one, and the result is an rvalue pair which binds to the `P&&`-overload  of the `insert` function.

(Another option is to use `emplace()` with `piecewise_construct` and `forward_as_tuple`, though that would get a lot more verbose.)

I suppose the moral here is that list-initializers look for viable overloads – but they have to know what to look for!

Comment: Yes, that's basically what I wrote before deleting my answer. I have a doubt though: why is an `initializer_list<>` created here? `std::pair<int, non_copyable>` does not seem to have a constructor that takes one. I thought the uniform initialization syntax would just pick the regular constructor of `pair<>`.

Comment: Also, initializer_list<> elements must be all of the same type, no?

Comment: +1 to both comments. There shouldn't even be an `initializer_list` in my example. It's more like a call to `std::pair`'s constructor using uniform initialization.

Comment: I suppose what's surprising is that `map` does *not* have an `insert` overload for `value_type &&`, while `vector` does.

Comment: @KerrekSB C++17 added one, BTW

Comment: @n.caillou: Thanks, four-years-from-the-future person :-)

Comment: I nevertheless appear to be programming six years ago, since I ran into this very problem!

Comment: Is there any solution for C++03? I am programming 10 years ago :'-(

Comment: @Fabian: You mean you have a non-copyable type in C++03? I don't think a std::map will work with that directly, though you could build your own "fork" that has a dedicated "emplace-like" insertion function for your specific data type, if you really need this feature. Or you could use more indirection and store pointers, but that wouldn't quite be comparable.

Answer (score 0):

Besides other answers of providing move (assignment) constructor, you could also store the non-copyable object through pointer, especially `unique_ptr`. `unique_ptr` will handle resource movement for you.

Comment: This is confusing answer. unique_ptr will not handle resource movement of the object, but rather you are storing only the pointer to the object itself, therefore no resources of the object are moved - only the unique_ptr itself is moved.